# LinkedIn Oauth v2 Authorization returns internal_error

Tags: linkedin-api

I attempting to obtain an Authorization Code (as specified in [step 2 of these instructions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/linkedin/shared/authentication/authorization-code-flow?context=linkedin/context#step-1-configure-your-application))

I am redirecting the user to the URL:
https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/authorization?response_type=code&client_id={MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE}&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2F127.0.0.1%3A9001%2Fapi%2Fauth%2Flinkedin%2Fcallback&scope=r_liteprofile%20r_emailaddress%20w_member_social&state=hot123dog456

In this URL {MY_CLIENT_ID_HERE} is being swapped out for my actual client ID. The user gets redirected correctly and is able to login, after which they are redirected to the correct call back page (https://127.0.0.1:9001/api/auth/linkedin/callback).

The problem is the request I receive in the callback response query is just a generic error with no additional information:

```
{ 
  error: 'internal_error',
  error_description: 'Internal Server Error',
  state: 'hot123dog456' 
}
```

I've tried using different scopes and different states, but am not sure what else to do. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you're still seeing issues, please submit a ticket to linkedin.zendesk.com.

Comment: did you fix your issue? what was that? cc@ChristopherOu